# How to use yes command in python Linux based machines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to execute linux commands from python. I am using subprocess to execute linux commands.

if file already exist it will ask to overwrite like below

```
  Overwrite (y/n)?
```

In Linux i will pass command like below:

```
 yes | somecommand option1 option2
```

if file already exist it sends y option to overwrite.

Here is the python script example:

```
 import subprocess
 subprocess.call(["somecommand", "option1", "option2"])
```

Now how to pass option y in python3 if it only prompt for y/n option